# ggplot: Create X Symbol in Specific Point in Line Graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to have X Symbol in two points of line graphs where 0 values are shown.

I have data as following:

```
data <- read.table(text = "
Clients Throughput Systems ErrorBar
250    2494 Za     72.986
500    2491 Za     104.854
750    401  Za     130.034
1000   0    Za     0
1250   0    Za     0
250    2501 ZCT 58.987
500    2499 ZCT 89.927
750    2380 ZCT 130.475
1000   2321 ZCT 139.450
1250   2296 ZCT 142.580", header = TRUE)
```

The script to draw the line graph as follows:

```
plot1 <- ggplot(data=data , aes(x=Clients, y=Throughput, group=Systems, colour = Systems, shape=Systems)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Throughput-Error, ymax=Throughput+Error), width=20.5, colour="black") +
  geom_line(size=1.2) +
  geom_point(size=2.3)

plot1 <- plot1 + scale_y_continuous(breaks= seq(0,3000,500), limits = c(0,3000)) + 
  labs(x="Number of clients") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(250,500,750,1000,1250)) + 
  labs(y="Throughput (abds/sec)")

plot1 <- plot1 + scale_colour_manual(values=c("#00ff00","#0000ff"))

plot1 <- plot1 + theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom") + 
  labs(fill="", colour=" ", shape=" ") + 
  theme(text = element_text(size=18)) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(keywidth = 0.8, keyheight = 0.01))

plot1
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add X symbols using `annotate`:

```
data <- read.table(text = "
Clients Throughput Systems Error
250    2494 Za     72.986
500    2491 Za     104.854
750    401  Za     130.034
1000   0    Za     0
1250   0    Za     0
250    2501 ZCT 58.987
500    2499 ZCT 89.927
750    2380 ZCT 130.475
1000   2321 ZCT 139.450
1250   2296 ZCT 142.580", header = TRUE)

plot1 <- ggplot(data=data , aes(x=Clients, y=Throughput, group=Systems, colour = Systems, shape=Systems)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Throughput-Error, ymax=Throughput+Error), width=20.5, colour="black") +
  geom_line(size=1.2) +
  geom_point(size=2.3)

plot1 <- plot1 + scale_y_continuous(breaks= seq(0,3000,500), limits = c(0,3000)) + 
  labs(x="Number of clients") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(250,500,750,1000,1250)) + 
  labs(y="Throughput (abds/sec)")

plot1 <- plot1 + scale_colour_manual(values=c("#00ff00","#0000ff"))

plot1 <- plot1 + theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom") + 
  labs(fill="", colour=" ", shape=" ") + 
  theme(text = element_text(size=18)) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(keywidth = 0.8, keyheight = 0.01))+
  annotate("Text", x=data$Clients[data$Throughput==0],
                   y=data$Throughput[data$Throughput==0], label="X", size=6)

plot1
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for. Thank you indeed @Marco Sandri

Comment: I have just encountered an another issue, when I have 0 in 750, 1000 and 1250, it only shows X symbol in 1000 and 1250. How to add X in 750 data point as well?